# teradata export from hive to teradata class not found

Tags: teradata

I am trying to export from hive table to teradata using TDCH connector, I am getting below errror:-

```
15/05/07 08:01:03 INFO tool.ConnectorExportTool: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/MetaException
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
            at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorJobRunner.runJob(ConnectorJobRunner.java:81)
            at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorExportTool.run(ConnectorExportTool.java:61)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
            at com.teradata.hadoop.tool.TeradataExportTool.main(TeradataExportTool.java:24)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
            ... 13 more
```

I understand from error that hive-metastore jar is missing. But it is already there in hive/lib folder

```
 hive-metastore.jar -> hive-metastore-0.9.0.jar
```

Is already present in the path: `/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/hive/lib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define environment variables LIB_JARS and HADOOP_CLASSPATH.
You can use the environment variable LIB_JARS with the parameter -libjars

You can find an example under https://developer.teradata.com/sites/all/files/Teradata%20Connector%20for%20Hadoop%20Tutorial%20v1%200%20final.pdf.

According to the README, following jars are necessairy:

```
    Hive Job(version 0.11.0 as example):
         a) hive-metastore-0.11.0.jar
         b) hive-exec-0.11.0.jar
         c) hive-cli-0.11.0.jar
         d) libthrift-0.9.0.jar
         e) libfb303-0.9.0.jar
         f) jdo2-api-2.3-ec.jar
         g) slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
         h) datanucleus-core-3.0.9.jar
         i) datanucleus-rdbms-3.0.8.jar
         j) commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
         k) commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
         l) antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
         m) datanucleus-api-jdo-3.0.7.jar

    HCatalog Job:
         a) above Hive required jar files
         b) hcatalog-core-0.11.0.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/MetaException` class is not available to `java runtime`. can you ensure that the Jar is under valid `runtime classpath`.

few try outs can be try passing the classpath explicitly to jvm via -cp , alternatively you can try putting the jar in launch directory to ensure its present.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may have all the jar files in your "lib" folder, but for some reason Oozie may not be reading it simply because you have a typo in your job.properties or coordinator.properties. Double check your properties file.

The "job.properties" file should read like the following -

```
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/apps/myapp/workflow/
```

The "coordinator.properties" file should read like the following -

```
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.coord.application.path=${nameNode}/apps/myapp/workflow/
```

and your "lib" folder with jars should be at -

```
/apps/myapp/workflow/lib
```