# Sqoop Export from hive table to teradata table

Tags: hive, export, teradata, sqoop, hcatalog

I am trying to load data from hive to teradata.
For that purpose, I have created an external table in hive, inserted values into it, and ran a sqoop export command.

```
create external table Sample_load
(
name varchar(32),
addr varchar(50),
);

insert into table Sample_load select F_name, Address from data where age > 18;

sqoop export -Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=pwd_file_for_connection-
Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=" -Duser.timezone=GMT" --connect jdbc_url/database=Tera_db,charset=utf8 -m 
10 --username uname --password-alias pwd --table Teradata_table --hcatalog-database db_name -- 
hcatalog-table sample_load ;
```

but Im getting the following error :

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:42)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:766)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatSplit
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.teradata.connector.hcat.ConnectorCombineFileHCatSplit.<init>(ConnectorCombineFileHCatInputFormat.java:276)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:42)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:766)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

        at com.teradata.connector.hcat.ConnectorCombineFileHCatSplit.<init>(ConnectorCombineFileHCatInputFormat.java:281)
        ... 15 more

21/01/05 03:21:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1608639506866_65714_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:42)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:766)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatSplit
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.teradata.connector.hcat.ConnectorCombineFileHCatSplit.<init>(ConnectorCombineFileHCatInputFormat.java:276)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:42)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:766)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

        at com.teradata.connector.hcat.ConnectorCombineFileHCatSplit.<init>(ConnectorCombineFileHCatInputFormat.java:281)
        ... 15 more

21/01/05 03:21:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1608639506866_65714_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:42)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:766)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatSplit
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.teradata.connector.hcat.ConnectorCombineFileHCatSplit.<init>(ConnectorCombineFileHCatInputFormat.java:276)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:42)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:766)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

        at com.teradata.connector.hcat.ConnectorCombineFileHCatSplit.<init>(ConnectorCombineFileHCatInputFormat.java:281)
        ... 15 more

21/01/05 03:21:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
21/01/05 03:21:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1608639506866_65714 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1608639506866_65714_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0 killedMaps:0 killedReduces: 0

21/01/05 03:21:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 9
        Job Counters
                Failed map tasks=4
                Launched map tasks=4
                Other local map tasks=3
                Data-local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=76036
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=19009
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=19009
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=77860864
21/01/05 03:21:16 INFO processor.TeradataOutputProcessor: output postprocessor com.teradata.connector.teradata.processor.TeradataBatchInsertProcessor starts at:  1609834876349
21/01/05 03:21:16 INFO processor.TeradataBatchInsertProcessor: drop stage table "Sample_A01_032038570"
21/01/05 03:21:16 INFO processor.TeradataOutputProcessor: output postprocessor com.teradata.connector.teradata.processor.TeradataBatchInsertProcessor ends at:  1609834876349
21/01/05 03:21:16 INFO processor.TeradataOutputProcessor: the total elapsed time of output postprocessor com.teradata.connector.teradata.processor.TeradataBatchInsertProcessor is: 0s
21/01/05 03:21:16 INFO teradata.TeradataSqoopExportHelper: Teradata export job completed with exit code 1
21/01/05 03:21:16 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export:
Import Job failed
        at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager.exportTable(TeradataConnManager.java:550)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:94)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:113)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:187)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:241)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:250)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:259)
21/01/05 03:21:16 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient: Closed a connection to metastore, current connections: 1
```

When checked the logs, I couldnt find the map process running, i.e it has failed even before the map process could start
Please help me out to find out the issue.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30100592/2700344

Comment: If you really need HCatalog, you need to define HCAT_HOME, something like `export HCAT_HOME=/usr/local/hive/hcatalog`.